# Creating a custom copy of pagestyle plain with fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr, pdfpages

Consider this MWE (compiles with `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{insert.tex}
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %delete everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove the horizontal line in the header
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase\leftmark} %even page - chapter title
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase\rightmark} %uneven page - section title
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{AX-\thepage} %page number on all pages

\immediate\write18{pdflatex insert.tex} % compile this, to insert as pdf

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Test section}

So, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah ...

\clearpage

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{insert.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Here, the first page outputs "AX-1" as pagenumber; but the included pdf shows just "2", because I use `pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}`.

I would like to have page number "AX-2" on the second page too - but if I use `pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}`, while I get "AX-2" there, I also get the section header which I don't want.

What I'd want ideally is to make a "copy" of the `plain` pagestyle, say named as `plainB`, and only redefine `\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{AX-\thepage}` for it; so I could use it as `pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plainB}` and have only the customized page number "AX-2" output.

Is this possible at all to do - and if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: possibly related: [FancyHDR Package - Define Custom Styles? • Text Formatting • LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=10127); [Definition of a new Page Style • Page Layout • LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=20616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new page style. For example:

```
\fancypagestyle{customplain}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhf[cf]{<whatever>}%
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}}
```

and then use it as you wish.

Comment: Many thanks for that @cfr, worked great: I used `pagecommand=\thispagestyle{customplain}`, and inside the handler, both `\fancyhf[CF]{AX-\thepage}` and `\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{AX-\thepage}` seem to work the same (and as expected). Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Yes. I just tend to use the `\fancyhf` version for whatever reason. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

To make a copy of an existing page style, include it in your new page style and redefine whatever you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

% fancy page style
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[L]{LH}\fancyhead[C]{CH}\fancyhead[R]{RH}
\fancyfoot[L]{LF}\fancyfoot[C]{CF}\fancyfoot[R]{RF}

% New fancy page style
\fancypagestyle{newfancy}{
  \pagestyle{fancy}% Duplicate fancy page style
  \fancyhead[C]{ch}% Update components of fancy
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-5]

\lipsum[1-5]
\pagestyle{newfancy}

\end{document}
```

`\pagestyle{<style>}` (and `\thispagestyle{<style>}`) is purely a directive to execute a bunch of macros (contained within `\ps@<style>`). That's why calling the page style from within another is okay - it sets the "defaults" associated with the original style, together with any modifications you include after it.

Comment: This is interesting but it doesn't seem to work for `plain`.

Comment: @cfr: Can you provide an example?

Comment: 3.5 years later?! For all I know, whatever I tried works now. If you have any idea what I might have meant, I might be able to figure out some more details. Why do you think I wanted it with `plain`?

Comment: I'm not responsible for the down-vote, by the way. If that's what you're wondering. At least, the system says I'm not. I assume it is right. And it seems independently plausible.

Comment: Possibly: that if you substitute `plain` for `fancy` in the definition of `newfancy`, you do not get what you might expect. That is, it makes no difference whether you use `fancy` or `plain` in the definition of `newfancy`: the result is the same. Similarly, `empty` etc. I don't think you can clone the styles this way, at least in these cases. But probably I misunderstood your answer and you meant something else.